# Switcheroo - Which switch turns on the light bulb?

Tags: logical-deduction

There is a famous puzzle, asked several times on this site, regarding a light bulb hidden in a room. There are three switches outside. You can flip them however you want, but you cannot continue flipping them once you've opened the door to the bulb. How do you figure out which switch connects to the bulb? The answer, which I'll put in spoilers for those who don't know yet, is:

> You flip one switch on, wait a few minutes, flip it off, and flip another switch on, then open the door. If it's on, it's the second switch. If it's off, but it's hot, it's the first switch. If it's off, but cold, it's the switch you didn't touch.

My question is as follows: Assuming you don't have a thermometer, can you increase the total number of switches beyond three and still be able to tell which switch connects to the bulb?

Once you're done with this one, [check out the sequel.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35394/switcheroo-2-monty-hall)

Comment: I'm afraid this is at least the fourth time this famous puzzle has Bern posted here. See, e.g., http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5977/shedding-some-light

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which switch goes to which bulb?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27/which-switch-goes-to-which-bulb)

Comment: Though the corollary might be new.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Absolutely right. I apologize - I did a search but couldn't find this riddle. I'll edit the question to make the focus of the question on the corollary.

Comment: @Inazuma: I guess I wasn't so clear on what I meant by the corollary. In this example, there are three switches, one of which is the correct switch. Can you increase the number of total switches beyond three and still be able to guess which switch is the correct one? Four? Five? Ten? Could you go indefinitely?

Comment: @DonielFilreis Ah okay, much more interesting now. I have deleted my answer (since it can be found in the links attached).

Comment: The answer you put in spoiler tags is spoiled when you ask the question.  "Assuming you don't have a ..."

Comment: This seems kinda open-ended to me. I mean, if you know roughly how fast a lightbulb cools, you could probably do 5 or 6 with reasonable accuracy. Also, some lightbulbs can explode with a power surge, so you could stick a sensitive microphone on the door and then overload each circuit in turn until it records a pop. Just depends on how much you want to stretch the premise

Comment: @PatrickN: I had assumed answers like that would be covered with the "no thermometer" rule. Since we're dealing with logic puzzles, my point was to see how far you could logically extend the answer to the original question.

Comment: @DonielFilreis So, just for the sake of precision, you're saying that we can only determine whether a lightbulb is hot or cold, with no granularity outside of those two states?

Comment: @PatrickN: Yep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), if I'm interpreting the problem space correctly, should put an absolute upper bound of four switches on the question as it stands.

You have given a restriction that temperature is a binary state: hot or cold.  Assuming the only other output is whether the light is shining, we have only four states:

1. Hot and Lit => A
2. Hot and Unlit => B
3. Cold and Lit => C
4. Cold and Unlit => D

The pigeonhole principle says every possibility has to go into one of those buckets, A-D.  So if you had 5 switches, at least one of those buckets is guaranteed to have two possible entries (e.g. B = Switch 1 OR Switch 5).  Now just from the nature of the outputs, we can't even get those 4 switches, but that's less theoretical and more nuanced.

Edit:

That said if you're looking for more cutesy answers, you can stretch it to four with a third output:

> Whether the filament is intact (assuming a quality lightbulb).  Flip switch one.  Wait 100 years, then turn it off.  Flip switch two for 5 minutes, then turn it off.  Flip switch three.  Enter the room.  If the bulb's filament is destroyed, it was switch one.  If it's hot but off, it was switch two.  If it's on, it was switch three.  Otherwise, it's switch four.

Comment: That is indeed the correct answer. Four is the maximum. The only difference between this and the original is that "cold and lit" means that the switch was just turned on, while "hot and lit" means that it's been on for a while. Like you said; if you want to examine the filament or whether the ceiling caught on fire, you can extend it, but realistically speaking, four is the maximum.

Comment: @DonielFilreis: It's unclear to me how you could actually use Cold and Lit to extend this to four switches.  Four is definitely an upper bound, but that doesn't in itself make it possible.  Can you describe the algorithm you're thinking of that can actually make use of "Cold and Lit?"  Everything I come up with breaks down.

Comment: @MarkPeters Lol +1 for "Wait 100 years."

Comment: @MarkPeters: Why is there an issue with having a bulb that's cold and lit? If you don't wait too long between flipping the switch and feeling the bulb, it should still be relatively cool.

Comment: @DonielFilreis: That's not the issue...the issue is what then are the steps you do before going in the room, and therefore what does it mean (i.e. which switch is connected) if the bulb is cold and lit?  The best I could say is "Turn switch 1 on for 1 minute, then off.  Turn switch 2 on and leave it on.  After a minute, turn switch 3 on and immediately enter the room."  If cold and unlit, 4.  If cold and lit, 3.  If hot and lit, 2.  If  hot and unlit, 1.  Problem with that last case is, in the minute that switch 1 was off, it would've cooled down again.

Comment: I guess I assumed, as, from all the models I've seen, everyone else seems to assume, that once you turn a switch on and it gets hot, it doesn't cool down. (Remember, this is the same theoretical world where leaving a switch on for 100 years and still being able to come back and turn it off, or even remembering it's on, is entirely plausible.) Thus, if switch 1 was the switch, it would be hot and unlit. If switch 2 was the switch, it would be hot and lit. If switch 3, cold and lit, since it didn't warm up yet, and if switch 4, then cold and unlit.

Answer (score 1):

In the classic solution when you enter the room there are only 3 possible states the bulb can be in

> HOT and OFF 
>  COLD and OFF 
>  ON

Because the state of the bulb leads you directly to which switch is connected, it is impossible to extend this puzzle to more switches unless you either

> allow the door to be opened multiple times

or allow consideration of more than 3 states as alluded to by use of a thermometer eg. a simple extension to 4 switches would be

> HOT and OFF 
>  COLD and OFF 
>  ON 
>  WARM and OFF